# Which C# field creates an Azure Table Storage column as “date” type

Tags: c#, azure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shNs1.png)

I want to read `_updatedAt` field, but when I use `DateTime` type in C#, it will always return a wrong date like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WnaF.png)

It will be appreciated if someone could point out what mistake I made.

Comment: What do you mean by `it will always return a wrong date`? Because you have not initialized the variable by yourself, the value will be initialized to the default valye (which is DateTime.MinValue) and that's what you're getting.

Comment: I want to read the "_updatedAt" field in a C# console application, following this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/ , I'll get the right value if the field type is string or bool, but I can't get "_updatedAt" field right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an mistake, actually there should be two underscores _ before the "updatedAt" field, I typed only one _. The DateTime format is right.